# Not sure how to use Application Default Credentials

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently working on a Flask project and I want to host it on Google Cloud App Engine. Since I want to store sessions, I came across the service named FireStore. To use that service, I need to use Google Application Credentials, which I am not sure how to use.

My code:

```py
...

from google.cloud import firestore
from google.oauth2 import service_account

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'application_default_credentials.json'

app = Flask(__name__ )
db = firestore.Client()
sessions = db.collection('sessions')

...
```

But once I use my software, I get the following error, which I've been struggling to fix for the last few hours.

> AttributeError: you need a private key to sign credentials.the credentials you are currently using <class 'google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials'> just contains a token. see https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html#setting-up-a-service-account for more details.

I clicked on the link and read the documentation, but it didn't really help me understand the problem, let along fixing it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If you want to use the credentials set up by the gcloud CLI (aka Application Default Credentials), remove the line that starts with `os.environ ...`. The file `application_default_credentials.json` is not a service account JSON key file. That file is an OAuth secrets file the CLI uses to create and refresh credentials. For more information, refer to the documentation on how to set up credentials. https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for your comment. If I get rid if that line, I still get the same error.

Comment: How did you authorize the gcloud CLI? You want to use `gcloud auth application-default login`. Run that command and try again. Also refer to the documentation link in my first comment and @guillaume-blaquiere answer.

Answer (score 3):

ADC, or [Application Default Credential](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc), is a mechanism implemented in the Google Cloud client libraries

TL;DR: For letting the magic happens, remove the lines

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'application_default_credentials.json'
```

And run your code locally and on Google Cloud APp Engine. It works!!

---

For more details, because nothing is magic, the first things to know is that service account key files are a bad practice, even if Google Cloud tutorial propose to use them.

ADC is a powerful mechanism that look into the runtime environment the available credential:

1. First, check is the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var exists
2. If not, check if the [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview) exist in the environment (always the case when you run the app on Google Cloud). The metadata server provides the credential defined by the runtime service account (by default on App Engine, `<projectID>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`)
3. If not, look into the "well known location", it means it looks for user credential stored in your machine. the `application_default_credentials.json` file generated by the command `gcloud auth login`
4. Perform unauthenticated calls

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. If I remove the line, I still get the same error: `AttributeError: you need a private key to sign credentials.the credentials you are currently using <class 'google.auth.compute_engine.credentials.Credentials'> just contains a token. see https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html#setting-up-a-service-account for more details.`

Comment: I tested and it works well with my user credential and Python. Be sure to have the latest library version installed on your environment

Answer (score 0):

`application_default_credentials.json` should be a service account key.

First, you have to [create a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts-create) with appropriate roles to access firestore. Then [download key file](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/keys-create-delete).